# No viable alternative at input 'JSON' exception in cqlsh. Not able to insert JSON in Cassandra table

Tags: cqlsh

I am trying to insert a JSON in Cassandra table using shell and Java code but getting this error:
 **No viable alternative at input JSON**

1. Cassandra Versions:
    [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.12 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
2. Table Creation script
    CREATE TABLE users(id int PRIMARY KEY, age int, state text);
3. Insert script
    INSERT INTO users JSON '{"id": 888, "age": 42, "state": "TX"}';
4. Similar code for insert using Java:
    String cqlStatement = "INSERT INTO users JSON '{\"id\":888 , \"age\":21 ,\"state\":\"TX\"}'";
       cassandraTemplate.execute(cqlStatement);

Getting exception in both the case as :
    **No viable alternative at input 'JSON'**
5. Do I need to set up something in Cassandra to accept JSON command in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with your version 2.0.12.  Looks like Cassandra 2.2 is the minimum version that supports "INSERT INTO users JSON ...".

With < 2.2 the alternatives are captured here:

[insert JSON String in Apache-Cassandra 0.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039846/insert-json-string-in-apache-cassandra-0-8-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score -1):

**Found answer for the question which works in Cassandra 2.0.12 as well**

**Prerequisite :**

1. Minified version of JSON to insert in the table
2. Link http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx can be used to minify the JSON (Go to this site and copy the JSON
   content, minify and    copy the output)
3. Check for any single quote('), replace it by double quote('')
4. Make sure string is not terminating
5. JSon should be inserted in **text** column

In the given sample a table with the name employee has been created which has 4 columns. Eid an integer value, ename a text value, ephonenumber as list of text and eaddress as text. eaddress is the column where JSON is supposed to be inserted

**Steps to execute:**

1. Create a table lets say **employee** with 4 columns eid, ename, ephonenumber, eaddress with primary key eid

Command to execute in CQL terminal:

**create table employee(eid int, ename text, ephonenumber list, eaddress text, primary key(eid));**

2. Insert a row in employee table with ephonenumber as list and eaddress as json

   Command to execute in CQL terminal

**insert into employee (eid, ename, ephonenumber, eaddress) values(1, 'Sourav', ['7773330000', '5550003333'], '{"office":"197 - ITPL - Bangalore","home":"196 -Thubarahalli - Bangalore"}');**

3. Check using select query if JSON string has been inserted

**Select * from employee**